# MLKit process completion closure not running on private or global queue

Tags: swift, google-mlkit

In my project I'm using Google MLKit for face detecting like this:

```
lazy var faceOption: FaceDetectorOptions = {
    let options = FaceDetectorOptions()
    options.performanceMode = .accurate
    options.landmarkMode = .all
    options.classificationMode = .all
    return options
}()

faceDetector = FaceDetector.faceDetector(options: faceOption)
let visionImage = VisionImage(buffer: buffer)
faceDetector.process(visionImage) { faces, error in
    //doing some works
}
```

Inside the completion handler closure, the code runs on the main thread (I check it with `Thread.isMainThread` and it returns `true`).

For some reasons (have some lags) I want to run this part of codes (doing some works) on private or global queue. I tried it by using this codes:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
faceDetector.process(visionImage) { faces, error in
    guard error == nil, let faces = faces else {
        return
    }
    
    queue.async {
        //doing some works
    }
}
```

but the problem is none of the lines inside `queue.async` (doing some additional work) are running at all.

My question is why this is not working inside `queue.async` and how can i running this part of codes (doing some works) inside another queue (private or global queue)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [API reference doc](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/reference/swift/mlkitfacedetection/api/reference/Classes/FaceDetector#process_:completion:):

`process(_:completion:)`

is designed to be called from the main thread: `completion   Handler to call back on the main thread with faces detected or error.`

If you want to call it from other thread, `results(in:)` is the one: [link](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/reference/swift/mlkitfacedetection/api/reference/Classes/FaceDetector#resultsin:)